# Alias for rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My model name in one of rails app is `OrganizationUser`  and is there any way to create alias name for this model as OU or OrgUser so that I can use in rails console..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795809/class-alias-in-ruby

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If kishie's answer does not suit you you could create another model that inherits from OrganizationUser:

```
class OU < OrganizationUser
end
```

or

```
class OrgUser < OrganizationUser
end
```

Comment: This is actually a little risky under a few circumstances, particularly with STI models, or for anything that expects specific class types. It'll work, but makes me a little nervous.

Comment: @DaveNewton: To tell the truth I totally missed that the op's goal was to use the names in the console, in which case I would have gone for kishie's answer (OU = OrganizationUser), I've used that in the past myself. However I don't see a problem with the above code if what you are looking after is just using a different name for a given class.

Comment: Under STI it would create the wrong type column in the DB; this *may* not be a problem, but it introduces a type hierarchy that doesn't really exist. Not *necessarily* an issue, like I said, but IMO not a great idea--YMMV :)

Comment: OU = OrganizationUser works well, but where can I put that so that it automatically runs every time I run rails c?

Comment: @RomanGaufman Playing with Rails 7 I created `renamers/u.rb` inside of the `app` folder with just one line: `U = User`. You should be able to do something similar to that for your class.

Answer (score 1):

To work on a more cleaner side . Suppose you have a model

```
   class Home < ActiveRecord::Base
      class << self
        def agent
            p "This is a Dummy String"
       end
    end
    end
```

Step 1

Create a alias.rb inside your lib.  Which will contain your Alias mappings and Constants holding those mapping

```
module Alias
C = Home #to make a alias of class
H = Home.new  #a class object alias
end
```

Step 2

Goto rails c

```
rails c
"inside it for loading"
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.1)
ruby-1.9.3-preview1 :001 > require 'alias'
 => true

ruby-1.9.3-preview1 :002 > include Alias
 => Object 

ruby-1.9.3-preview1 :003 > C
 => Home(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

ruby-1.9.3-preview1 :004 > H
 => #<Home id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```