# Rails model alias gets "uninitialized constant" from relation call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, alias

When making a relation like `belongs_to :author` I've always used the option `:class_name => 'User'` but I never liked it. It isn't semantic, IMO.

So I was thinking about an alias for my `User` model. "Well", I thought, "a model is simply a constant, so let's put another name to it.

Then I wrote `Author = User` and saved it in `app/models/author.rb`.

Looked good, and worked well for all purposes except one. When I tried to use my relation, say  `post.build_author` I get `uninitialized constant Post::Author`.

Why can't ruby find my constant `Author` ?

Seems like `Post` can't reach it, so I tried this:

```
class Post
  def author_class_test
    Author
  end
end

=> Post.new.author_class_test
=> User(...)
```

So, I assume `Post` can "see" `Author`. But not when working with relations, does anybody knows why is that ?

Thanks in advance.

**Update.**

So, out of curiosity I tried this:

```
class Post
  Author = User
  ...
end
```

Then again `Post.new.build_author` which again got me `uninitialized constant Post::Author`. But at least now I know he's lying to me. :P

The trace ends here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb#L142

I'm starting to think it's an edge case which ActiveRecord does not considers.

Answer (score 0):

One way that I see you could do this is by creating a module where you store those aliases.

For instance:

```
module UserAliases
  Author = User
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UserAliases
  # ...
end
```

Put the module somewhere in your app, require it and include it in your model and that should do the trick. Let me know if that works.

Comment: After doing a bit of digging I found the following suggesting similar approaches http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154584/alias-for-rails-model and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795809/class-alias-in-ruby about pure Ruby object aliases that describe what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Class.new`.

You can see in the backtrace, that rails is attempting to build the type of the association using [`compute_type`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb#L142). In order for `compute_type` to work, the class name has to be correct.

Let's talk about what exactly we're doing when we define a class.

```
class A
  def self.foo
    puts "#{self.name} foo"
  end
end
```

This is the most common method to define a class, but it really just an alias for passing a block to `Class.new`. `Class.new` also accepts a parameter, which you can provide another class. When you pass a class to `Class.new`, it produces a new class with the passed in class set as its superclass. An example will clear this up:

```
B = Class.new(A)
C = A
```

Here we've got `B` and `C` which both share the same behavior as A. However, there are some important distinctions between assigning `A` to `C` and setting `A` as `B`'s superclass. The one which is relevant to you is this:

```
A.foo
B.foo
C.foo

#=> A foo
#=> B foo
#=> A foo
```

You'll see when we use assignment, `C` is not taking the name you're providing it. When we use `Class.new` we tell `B` to take the name we've given it, not the same name as the assigning class.

You're essentially creating a class that behaves like `User` even when you ask it what it's name is, but you're still calling the association `Author` without setting the class name.

Do this instead:

```
Author = Class.new(User)
```

Comment: Makes sense, but I think I tried inheritance before with no avail. I'll try again tomorrow at work, thanks!

Comment: No need for `Class.new`, just use inheritance the way you're used to: 

`class Author < User; end`

Comment: The problem is, they aren't interchangeable, for instance if I have a user and tries to assign to an `author` relation Rails raises `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Author(#70347245104340) expected, got User(#70347245222060)`.